# Generate unique and random code digit with MySQL

Tags: mysql, random, unique

Initial goal:

I would like to generate random and unique codes (6 digits) in a table.
I use a SQL query like this one to do that:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CRC32(RAND()), 1, 6) as myCode
FROM `codes`
HAVING myCode NOT IN (SELECT code FROM `codes`)
```

I asked me about how it will react when there will be no more available codes so I do the following test

---

Test context:

MySQL version: 5.5.20

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`code` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
UNIQUE (
`code`
)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Initial data:

```
INSERT INTO `codes` (`id`, `code`)
VALUES (NULL, '1'), (NULL, '2'), (NULL, '3'), (NULL, '4'), (NULL, '5'), (NULL, '6'), (NULL, '7'), (NULL, '8');
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CRC32(RAND()), 1, 1) as myCode
FROM `codes`
HAVING myCode NOT IN (SELECT code FROM `codes`)
```

---

By execute this query, I expect that it will always return 9 because it is the only code of one digit which does not exists.

But the result is:

- Sometime it return any rows
- **Sometime it return rows with values that already exists**

I don't understand this behavior so if someone can help :)

So the big question is:

> How MySQL can return rows with values that already exists?

Thanks

Comment: Just use AUTO_INCREMENT.  While not random it will be unique.  The requirement to be random appears to be value free.

Answer (score 2):

I would fill a `sequencetable` table with all the possible values, in sequence.

Then the random query just randomly selects records from the `sequencetable`, and each time it picks a record it deletes it. This way you will surely get all the numbers, without wasting time in finding a "hole" number (not already picked up).

```
CREATE TABLE `sequencetable` 
(
    `sequence` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`sequence`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Fill the sequence (no need for the AUTOINCREMENT actually).

```
DECLARE i INT;

SET i=1;
REPEAT
    INSERT INTO sequencetable VALUES (i);
    SET i=i+1;
UNTIL i>999999 END REPEAT;
```

Select a random record from the sequence (do this in a loop until records are available):

```
DECLARE sequencen INT;

SET sequencen = 
    (SELECT sequence FROM sequencetable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT  1);

DELETE FROM sequencetable WHERE sequence = sequencen;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vulkanino

I will certainly go through your solution but more than an alternative solution I don't understand the MySQL behavior...

**How MySQL can return values that I excluded with this part of my query:**
`HAVING myCode NOT IN (SELECT code FROM `codes`)`

Comment: SQL doesn't work that way, you want to exclude records as they are selected!

Comment: What do you mean by "you want to exclude records as they are selected" ?